# How to disable dates in Dynarch calendar

Tags: javascript, magento

I'm using Dynarch calendar in one of my Magento module and i want to disable some specific dates in an array like below.

```
var array = ["2014-01-14","2014-01-15","2011-01-16"]
```

I'm currently using this code and this disables all the days except sundays. I tried in many ways with JQuery methods and could not be success.

```
disableFunc : function(date)
    {  
        var y = calendar.date.getFullYear();
        var m = calendar.date.getMonth();     
        var d = calendar.date.getDate();

            var day_off_array = dayoff.split(",") ;
            //document.write(day_off_array);
            currentTime = new Date();
            var d1=currentTime.getDate();
            var m1=currentTime.getMonth();
            var y1=currentTime.getFullYear();

        if (date.getDay() != 0) { 
         return true; // true says "disable" 
         } else { 
         return false; // leave other dates enabled 
        } 

        if(y < y1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(m1 > m && y==y1)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Is there a way to achieve this and any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See examples at http://www.dynarch.com/jscal/#sec8

The above calendar allows selection between 8 April and 25 December 2009.

Here's the code that we used:

```
Calendar.setup({
  cont: "sample1",
  min: 20090408,
  max: 20091225
});
```

Comment: Thanks Gawai Creations. But i actually wanted a way to disable specific dates in the calendar and this is not suitable for that.